# Structure for holding a 16bits grayscale image

Tags: c#, linux, image, mask

I need to mask image from memory buffers (rectangle area filled with black). So I naively re-use the [Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Drawing_Imaging_PixelFormat_) class with [ImageFormat.MemoryBmp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.memorybmp?view=net-5.0) for my API. This works quite well on my local machine:

```cs
public static void MaskBitmap(Bitmap input, Rectangle maskRegion)
{
    var bytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(input.PixelFormat) / 8;
    var row = new byte[maskRegion.Width * bytesPerPixel];

    var maskData = input.LockBits(maskRegion, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, input.PixelFormat);
    for (var i = 0; i < maskData.Height; ++i)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(row, 0, maskData.Scan0 + (i * maskData.Stride), row.Length);
    }
    input.UnlockBits(maskData);
}
```

However when deploying to production it turns out that the following throw a `NotImplementedException`:

```
var image16 = new Bitmap(512, 512, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
```

I eventually tracked it down to here:

- https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/blob/6.0.4/src/bitmap.c#L848

So my question is: is there any existing class in c# that I can re-use to hold images of [pixelformat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=net-5.0) type:

- PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed:
- PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale:
- PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:

I know GDI+ [does not support saving/displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706842/136285) 16bits image, I simply need a memory structure with image-style access.

---

Just for reference, I tried the following hack:

```
var image = new Bitmap(512,512,PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
image.Flags = ImageFlags.ColorSpaceGray;
```

But [`Flags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageflags?view=net-5.0) is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you could see, the GDI+ `Bitmap` does not support the 16bpp grayscale pixel format on Linux at all, and actually its support is quite limited on Windows, too. Once I collected the limitations for both platforms, see the table under the **Restrictions of Possible Pixel Formats on Different Platforms** section [here](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_ConvertPixelFormat_1.htm).

> I need to mask image from memory buffers

To use completely managed in-memory representation of a bitmap both on Linux and Windows, you can use [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#managed-bitmap-data-manipulation) library (disclaimer: written by me). You can create a 16bpp grayscale bitmap data by the [`BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_BitmapDataFactory_CreateBitmapData.htm) method, which returns an [`IReadWriteBitmapData`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IReadWriteBitmapData.htm) that allows a lot of managed operations (see the link that enlists the usable extension methods). You can even convert it to an actual `Bitmap` by the [`ToBitmap`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_BitmapDataExtensions_ToBitmap.htm) extension, but on Linux this converts the result to a `Bitmap` with 24bpp RGB pixel format.

Example:

```cs
var image16 = BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData(new Size(512, 512), PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
var row = image16.FirstRow;
do
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image16.Width; x++)
    {
        // row[x] uses a Color32 structure (8 bit per color) but raw access
        // enables you to use the full 16-bit color range:
        row.WriteRaw<ushort>(x, 32768); // 50% gray
    }
} while (row.MoveNextRow());
```

As for the 8bpp indexed and 24bpp RGB formats, these are supported by the native `Bitmap` also on Linux, but please note that starting with version .NET 6 `System.Drawing` will be supported [only on Windows by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only). Microsoft recommends using [other libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action) instead, but you can still enable the Unix support by adding `"System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true` to `runtimeconfig.json`. Or, if you decide to use my library I mentioned above, just call `DrawingModule.Initialize()` before anything else, which [enables](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/01137b1b440819a82e3688ef98ade0dfb5f4379e/KGySoft.Drawing/Drawing/DrawingModule.cs#L90) the Unix support without editing any config files.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Wpf bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=net-5.0) should support 16-bit grayscale.

However, most systems I have worked on that uses 16-bit grayscale images uses a custom data type. Something like:

```
public class My16BitImage{
    public ushort[] Data {get;}
    public int Width {get;}
    public int Height {get;}
}
```

Note that for displaying the image you most probably need to convert it to an 8-bit image anyway, and you probably need to scale the values to make the max/min values map to the largest/smallest 8 bit values.

Comment: Unfortunately WPF cannot be used on Linux.

Comment: Seems like WPF is the [way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40179536/136285).